# How to get GitHub account to show up on Google search

Tags: github, google-search

My question is the same as in the link provided below but when I go to Google Search Console it asks me to verify my Github profile `https://github.com/[xyz]` by inserting an HTML file. I am unsure about how to do that or are there any other ways that I can verify my GitHub profile.

Similar question: [Force Github account to show up in google search](https://superuser.com/questions/728923/force-github-account-to-show-up-in-google-search/728930#728930?newreg=268c86d5366a4107a15dc33cf4d85e90)

Google serch console: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

Comment: Your question is 100% the same as the other question. You are simply implying that somehow if you add your page to the Google Search Console it somehow will push your GitHub profile up in Google’s index for searches. That is not how it works. That HTML file you mention is to verify ownership of a domain; you obviously don’t own `github.com` and that will not work. Google Search Console is strictly a tool for websites you own; not something that you can use to force another site’s pages to come up higher in rank because you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

What is Google Search Console? Google automatically indexes Github. If you just created the Github account, have patience, will appear in Google searches after a while. Just to make sure, go in Google and search for (where `[xyz]` is the name of your profile/username):

```
[xyz] site:github.com
```

You should see a result with the link towards your google user main page.

Answer (score 0):

## You cannot use the Google Search Console to affect indexing results on a site you do not control such as GitHub.

First, your question is 100% the same as the other question. You are simply implying that somehow if you add your page to the Google Search Console it somehow will push your GitHub profile up in Google’s index for searches. That is not how it works.

> …but when I go to Google Search Console it asks me to verify my Github profile `https://github.com/[xyz]` by inserting an HTML file.

That HTML file you mention is to verify ownership of a domain; you obviously don’t own `github.com` and that will not work. Google Search Console is strictly a tool for websites you own; not something that you can use to force another site’s pages to come up higher in rank because you want it to.

> I am unsure about how to do that or are there any other ways that I can verify my GitHub profile.

You are mixing up Google’s ranking results with your own GitHub profile. GitHub is a public website that gets crawled regularly. If you want your profile to show up in searches, you need to simply wait. You don’t control how Google will rank pages with your username nor can you force them to “verify” your specific repo.